# How to power Arduino nano and LED strip?

Tags: arduino-nano, electronics, led-strip

I am making a project that uses an Arduino nano and a sound detector module to power a 1m LED strip. I got the idea from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oRir4dck_w) and I am not sure how to power it. My LED strip flashes for a split second and turns off, and people say that the usb power source I am using is not enough power. I am worried though that if I use a more powerful power source that it will fry my Arduino. I am very new to this and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: How many LEDs on your strip? Is it an RGB, RGBW, or WS2812 strip?

Comment: it is WS2812 with 60 LEDs

Comment: When using a power source, which can provide more current with the same voltage, you cannot fry your Arduino with the change. The components will draw the current they need, not more. The rest is reserve and not a problem. You can only fry components, if you draw more current through them, as they are capable of. For example: You can fry your PCs USB port, if you draw too much power for lighting the LEDs. If you give power to too many LEDs through the Arduino (for example by using Vin for power and connecting the strip to 5V), the strip will draw too much power for the regulator and fry it.

Comment: Ok, so minimum current capacity you need is 60 * 0.02mA * 3, which is 3.6A. Plus some more to power the Arduino. You want a 4A power supply or better really.

Comment: That is for all LEDs on white and full brightness.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So if I use a 4A power source, can I connect it to the vin and then connect that to the 5v on the LED?

Comment: No. Use a 5V 4A power supply. Connect it to both the LED strip and the 5V of the Arduino.

Comment: ok, and I connect the gnd on the supply to the one on the LED strip and on the arduino, right?

Comment: Yep. Connect all grounds. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds

Comment: A simple solution would be to cut the LED strip to a shorter length (use fewer LED's).  If you avoid using full-on white you should be able to power 10 LED's from a standard USB port.

Comment: For the 5v4a power source, do you know where I could get the female part?

Answer (score 1):

WS2812 can draw 60mA when on full white, x 60 LEDs = 3.6A.  If you have a 4 to 5A external 5V supply powering all the components, you'd be okay.  If you're trying to power the strip from the Nano 5V line thru its regulator, the regulator will overheat and shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a relay and have a larger power supply that will light up the LED strip on the other side, after the relay gets the signal to turn on.

Comment: Is there any way I could do this without external hardware though? Apart from the sound detector, Arduino, led strip, some wires, and a usb cable,  I would prefer not to buy anything else, as I need this for a school project and it would take too long to ship.

Comment: @Ethangarret You could do it with just the battery and a transistor if you have those, otherwise probably not the arduino nano just can't supply the energy that is needed.

Comment: ok, thanks. Would it work if I power the led and Arduino separately?

Comment: Yes, and then you could use a switch to turn it on and off.

Comment: That is, if they are connected by that switch.

Comment: You don't need a relay or transistor here. The LEDs will only be turned on, if you tell them to do so over the data line. It needs just a strong enough power supply that is connected to the Arduino AND the LED strip directly (not through the Arduino). Over the data line the Arduino can then tell the LEDs to light up in the requested pattern.

Comment: @chrisl I was saying use a relay and transistor to turn it on and off. And what data line?

Comment: The OP stated in the comments, that he uses WS2812 LEDs. The WS2812 is actually the driver chip for every LED in the strip. And the LEDs in the strip actually consist of 3 LEDs in one case making them RGB. And the WS2812 chips are controlled via a single data pin. You can just write the value zero to every LED and the strip will be shut off. No need for a relay or transistor here.

Comment: But how would you right zero with the nano

Comment: The chips have their own protocol, but there are libraries like Adafruits Neopixel library or the FastLED library. There are tons of tutorials for that on the web, easily to find when you google WS2812 Arduino. You only need 1 pin for it. On setup you use the library function to initiate the strip with all LEDs off. I have build a room light with that myself.

Comment: @chrisl Oh that is interesting I’ll have to look into this sometime

Comment: @chrisl but the nano couldn’t supply the LEDs, but I see what you mean by no relay, I can’t believe I made that mistake, haha